# Can I represent this circuit like this

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, transmission-line

I want to do even-odd mode analysis, is representation of the circuit as shown below correct? Are these two circuits equivalent. Z is the characteristic impedances and theta are the electrical length of the TL.
[image: original circuit]
[image: another representation]

Comment: I'm voting to close this seems like homework without effort.

Comment: It is not a homework, and even if it is, i am providing my solution and I just want verification whether it is correct or not.

Comment: Ok I will retract my closing vote (I also don't know the answer, hope another has).

Comment: Yes.  They are electrically equivalent. 2Z1 || 2Z1 = Z1  Same for Z4.  Connections are good.